# Getting the Hex String from cipherText in Net Core

Tags: java, c#, .net-core

Currently doing a encryption in java which takes

1. API Secret. Perform Secret key hash algorithm by using SHA256. The resulted hash algorithm would be Encrypted Key = SHA256 (API Secret)
2. Request Raw Parameter(param) in JSon format encrypted using the Encrypted Key trough the AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding algorithm, and the ciphertext is converted into hexadecimal characters to be the value of the Encrypted data
   Encrypted Data = aesEcbPkcs5Padding (param, Encrypted key)

Here are the codes in Java

```
public static byte[] aesEcbPkcs5PaddingEncrypt(String content, String key) {        
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            byte[] aesKey = digest.digest(key.getBytes());
            SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(aesKey,"AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return cipher.doFinal(content.getBytes("utf-8"));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        return null;
    }
```

I Need to do the same encryption but using Net Core and C#.This is the code in C# Net Core
All i can do is something like this.

```
 public static byte[] aesEcbPkcs5PaddingEncrypt(String content, string secretKey)
        {
            byte[] hashBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey);
            byte[] cipher_content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

            using (AesManaged aes = new AesManaged())
            {
                byte[] encrypted = Encrypt(raw, aes.Key, aes.IV);
                // Print encrypted string    
                Console.WriteLine($ "Encrypted data: {System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encrypted)}");
                // Decrypt the bytes to a string.    
                string decrypted = Decrypt(encrypted, aes.Key, aes.IV);
            }
                SHA256 sha256 = SHA256Managed.Create();
            byte[] cryptPassword = sha256.ComputeHash(hashBytes);
            
        }
```

Is there any better solution/Correct solution in net core which will resulted with the same result as Java?

Comment: Do you need help writing the encrypt and decrypt functions?

Comment: @JohnV i just need to write the encrypt function. My encrypt in C# is not entirely correct with the Java Program that i wrote(it produce wrong result)

Comment: You need to share the code of your encrypt function then.

Comment: the second code block is in c# .Net Core, The first one is in Java.

Comment: You'll want to use the same key and iv for encryption in both your codes. You'll probably want to set it to a new byte array (all zeroes) or the correct length in C# if you're not setting it in Java. Honestly I think it would be better to use HMAC-SHA256 and pass the key to that instead of using AES and SHA256.